# Making report footer to appear just below the last page records

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-studio-2005, crystal-reports-2005

I am using Crystal Reports with VS-2005.

I have a report with a report footer section comprising of sum totals of a column. The problem is that in some cases, the records consume the entire page and the report footer alone appears on the next page. It looks awkward. I want the report footer to appear just below the last record row ended.

Is there any trick to make the report footer section fit on the last page itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you aren't using grouping, try this:

1. Add an additional section below your last detail section.
2. In Section Expert, mark the detail section Keep Together.
3. For the suppress formula for the new section, specify `Not OnLastRecord`.
4. Move the content from the report footer to the new detail section.

If you are using grouping, do this in the last group footer instead, and in Group Expert, mark the group Keep Group Together.